# Complex eloquent nested relationship queries with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, nested

So I am building out a query with eloquent in my laravel app. The query has many different relationships being brought into it and is set up like this below:

```
CourseEnrollment::whereIn('domain_id', $domain_ids)
    ->whereHas('member', function ($query) use ($filterUser) {
        if ($filterUser === 'true') {
            $query->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%@gmail.com%');
            $query->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%@yahoo.com%');
            $query->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%@boss.com%');
            $query->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%@test.com%');
        }
        $query->where('is_mentor', 1)->orWhere(function ($q) {
            $q->where('privileges', '!=', 0);
        });
    })->get();
```

If you look on the line that has the code $query->where(is_mentor, 1)->orWhere... you can see my attempt to try and create an orWhere situation that is using keys that are nested at two different points. Privileges is acutally not on the member relationship but is rather a key on the main CourseEnrollment table that I am querying. I need to be able to say if the enrollment.privileges are not equal to 0 or if the member.is_mentor key is equal to 1 then grab that enrollment, else don't grab that enrollment. As I have it right now I thought it was working but the issue I'm having is that when I combine this with the logic above that is filtering out emails, the orWhere is overriding that logic. For instance, I was filtering out all emails and this route should have been returning nothing but an enrollment was able to come through that had met both conditions of the orWhere statement. Is there a better way to compare differently nested keys in laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest group with where the query before use orWhere, for prevent not filter the previous wheres, is like add parenthesis enclosing the inner conditions.

```
CourseEnrollment::whereIn('domain_id', $domain_ids)
    ->whereHas('member', function ($query) use ($filterUser) {
        if ($filterUser === 'true') {
            $query->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%@gmail.com%');
            $query->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%@yahoo.com%');
            $query->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%@boss.com%');
            $query->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%@test.com%');
        }

        $query
            ->where(function ($sub) {
                $sub->where('is_mentor', 1);
                $sub->orWhere('privileges', '!=', 0);
            });
    })
    ->get();
```